# Equal Spacing in Navbar

Tags: css, html

I've made a "Sticky Navbar using CSS and HTML5 and I have 4 links to place on the navbar but I can't get them to space themselves ***Equally*** now before you say this is a duplicate and all, but first of all none of the solutions worked for me and second, I have a logo in the middle of the navbar... Some help Please!heres my website: catsonfire.tk

```
<style>
    article {
        margin: auto;
        height:auto;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    header {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 16px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: wheat;
        align-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        width:100%
    }
    nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #header_container ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main {
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    }
    #header_container ul li {
        display: inline;
        width: 25%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

        #header_container ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 39px;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 12px 0 13px 0;
        }

            #header_container ul li a:hover {
                color: #000;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px inset;
                -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px inset;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px inset;
            }
    #big {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 105px;
    }
    #header_container {
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index:1000;
        height:150px
    }

    #header {
        line-height: 60px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

- Home
- About

Comment: Before i say this is a duplicate and all, let me ask - How do we know what is the problem without seeing any of the code?

Comment: oops! completely forgot! im posting it

Comment: @TilwinJoy It would be fair to ask you to remove your down-vote now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site shows two links, but some thoughts:

```
#big ul{
    display:block;
}
#big li {
    display:block;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;    
}
#big li a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Makes the `li` element 1/4th of the width of its parent `ul`, then centers each `a` element in those. Add your styles as you want it to look.

Comment: doesnt work... its making my logo get pushed in the corner... do you think it will work when there are 4 logos? BTW: my logo should be in the CENTER

Comment: @aleks you need to rethink the html layout a bit. I would put the logo into its own `<li></li>`, so you would have [link][link][logo][link][link] in the `<ul>` up top, then set width to 20% each. You can then add more and change the width as you like.

Comment: Well I've finally got it working, and you can see the new version in a minute (on the same link)

Comment: @aleks Glad I could help. While you're at it, add a `transition: all 0.2s ease-in;` to your `#big li a` in your css, I think you'll like it.